# Inbox not showing up in Thunderbird on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, thunderbird

My Thunderbird and GMail were working just fine until recently Thunderbird started refusing to open my inbox! When I open Thunderbird the following screen shows and I just cannot access my e-mails (from the "Read messages" link as shown bellow and refuses to open my inbox. What am I doint wrong?

[image: Thunderbird]

Comment: What version of Thunderbird are you runnning?  Is your account IMAP or POP?

Comment: Are your accounts showing up as usual under "accounts"? (it's not shown in the picture)

Comment: I am on Thunderbird 9.0, IMAP, and my account GMail is showing under accounts. Still, I cannot access the Inbox, how do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I found was to delete ~/.thunderbird